# How to show a floating element in shiny only when hovering over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shiny, shinybs

*This question came about after my discovery that `bsTooltip` can't be used together with `shinyjqui`*

**In order to make this question understandable, I will explain what I know so far.**

I have been working on a rather large shiny App of ten of thousands of lines of code, building it one module at a time, and putting it into the main app once it's working.

Right now I have ran into a wall however where 2 features appear to be incompatible. I exchanged some messages with the author of `shinyjqui` and he told me that there is an old bug in `bootstrap` that makes it incompatible with shinyjqui: [issue github](https://github.com/Yang-Tang/shinyjqui/issues/19)

> Hi @madmark81 , this is an old bug of incompatible between jquery-ui
>   and bootstrap. Actually, attaching jquery-ui.js itself is enough to
>   break the tooltip without loading shinyjqui:

I would really love to combine `jqui_draggable`and `jqui_sortable` functionality, but also provide my users with `help messages` that pop up when you `hover` over `buttons` and other elements

I was thinking about making some `div` or `wellpanel` elements with the message in them and make them float, but at this point I don't know how to make sucha a solution work.

Recent experience has taught me that hover messages for ggplot do not cause a problem with shinyjqui... so there is hope perhaps. 
I do not know how to create this float effect myself however.

If anybody has ideas how to achieve this combination of floating messages and shinyjqui, I'd be very happy to hear about it, and to see how that could be done

What I build so far, is a `wellPanel` with a `z-index` of `100` to put it on top of other elements, but I would need to figure out how to make this `wellPanel` appear only on `hover` / `mouseover` events on the `actionButton` I want to link it to.

**App with just a tooltip:**

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyBS")  #needed to use bsTooltip
shinyApp(  
  ui = fluidPage(
    actionButton("Click", "Click Me"),
    bsTooltip(id = "Click", title = "hello message", placement = "right", trigger = "hover", options= list(container = "body", delay = list(show=100, hide=150)))
  ),

  server =  function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

**App with only shinyjqui functionality in it**

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyjqui")
shinyApp(      
  ui = fluidPage(
    jqui_resizable(
        actionButton("Click", "Click Me")
    )
  ),

  server =  function(input, output, session) {
  }
)
```

**App with combi (to illustrate broken message), and new hover approach idea**

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyjqui")
library("shinyBS")  #needed to use bsTooltip

## unload packages if needed for testing
# unload('shinyjqui')
# unload('shinyBS')


shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    h3("hello!"),
    jqui_resizable(
        actionButton("Click", "Click Me")
    ),

    ## this only works without loading shinyjqui
    ## use unload('shinyjqui') if you already loaded it
    bsTooltip(id = "Click", title = "hello message", placement = "right", trigger = "hover", options= list(container = "body", delay = list(show=100, hide=150))),

    ## This is the alternative so far, but needs to be only shown on hover
    uiOutput('hoverWell')
  ),

  server =  function(input, output, session) {

    output$hoverWell <- renderUI({
      wellPanel(h5('info message'), style = 'position:absolute; z-index:100; background-color: #e6f3f7; border-color: #339fff; left:85px; top:85px; height:40px;padding-top:0px')

    })
  }
)
```